# C what % symbol to access arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to access an a single row of a multidimensional array. However, I keep getting the following error message:
format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'.
I assume it's saying there's a particular format for arrays; what symbol do I use to access them if not %i?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int matrix1[5][4] =
        {{1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16},
        {17,18,19,20}};

    printf ("%i",matrix1[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which element do you want to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the first row of the array which will be converted to type `int *` that's the reason of your compiler's message.

If you want to print the whole row you can try with

```
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
    printf("%d ", matrix1[0][i]);
    /*                       ^ another index to specify an integer from the array */
printf("\n");
```

If you just want the first row and first column of the array try

```
printf("%d\n", matrix1[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it's saying there's a particular format for arrays

It's saying you are trying to use `%i`, which is for printing a single integer. There is no format to print an array directly, you have to provide your own glue around the `%i` format.

In other words, to print a row, you have to use something like:

```
printf ("%i %i %i %i", matrix1[0][0], matrix1[0][1], matrix1[0][2], matrix1[0][3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> what symbol do I use to access them if not `%i`?

There is no format specifier in the `printf` family of functions to print an array. The format specifiers only support writing primitive data types - `char`, `int`, etc. The full list can be found using `man printf`, at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf, and many other resources on the web.

To write all the elements from an array, you'll need to iterate over the items using a loop and write each element one by one, such as the code in [@iharob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398289/434551).